# How do you nest label elements inside of a ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="boxAnswer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">
   <Label Content="Label" Height="28" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="top" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Except I want  to be programmatically placed. When I call .IsAncestorOf on the boxAnswer it returns true but I can't set .IsDescendentOf on a label element even though I can create one programmatically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you care about IsAncestorOf and IsDescendentOf when all you want to do is just create the items in code? I would just do it like this ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "some text";
            scrollViewer.Content = textBlock;

Comment: That works fine, except you can only ever set it to be textBlock but not keep appending more and more textblocks. I want to know how to append rather than set. (though to be fair for some reason I thought .Content was only for strings so I never thought to put an object in there)

Comment: I'm trying to make a poor man's log, if you're wondering why I'm trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boxAnswer.Content = new Label()
                            {
                                 Content = "Label",
                                 Height = 28,
                                 Name = "label1",
                                 VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
                             };
```

Comment: Actually that doesn't solve the problem - you can only SET one but not append one.

Comment: Use a stack panel to hold your labels. Then set the Content of the scroll viewer with the stack panel.

Answer (score 2):

This -

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){
            Text = "some text"
    });
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){
            Text = "some text2"
    });
```

would be one way to do it. Although I think maybe you should take a look at ListBox or ListView as they may be a more fitting solution than a growing stackpanel. Maybe even just a multiline textblock.